# A function $f\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ with $f'(x)\not=0$ for all $x$ with no global inverse.

Tags: real-analysis, inverse-function-theorem

I don't think one exists, but the author of my text says it should. Here's why I don't such an $f$ exists. Suppose $f$ didn't have a global inverse, clearly $f$ is not injective for else we could define $$g:\text{Im}(f)\to \mathbb{R}$$ by $$y\mapsto x$$ where $f(x)=y.$ If $f$ is not injective, then $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ distinct. Then by the Mean Value Theorem there exists $c$ with 
$$0=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{a-b}=f'(c).$$
By contrapositive if $f'$ is non vanishing, then $f$ is injective, hence globally invertible.

Did I perhaps make a mistake, or is the author wrong in this case?

Comment: @IntegrateThis I asked about a function with no global inverse.

Comment: If $f$ gives you a real number, then you are indeed correct. Are you sure about the statement given by the author ? For example $f(x) = e^{ix}$ satisfies your condition, except that it returns a complex number, yet it does not have a global inverse.

Comment: @nicomezi I am absolutely sure that's the statement of the author. The exact text is 
"Give an example of a continuous differentiable function f on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)\not=0$ for every $x$ but such that $f$ does not have a global inverse."

Now just in case you think the author might have meant that $f'$ is not identically $0,$ earlier he tells us that this exercises is meant to use the Inverse Function Theorem to prove the existence of local inverses, but not a global inverse. If $f'(x)=0$ for some $x$ his previous statement would make no sense in relation to this.

Comment: As I understand the sentence, my example works then. $x \mapsto e^{ix}$ is continuous, differentiable and defined on $\mathbb{R}$. It does not ask you to give a function which returns a real number. As you have proven it, it is indeed not possible to find such function is this case. The purpose of that small exercise is probably to make you think about that property.

Comment: @nicomezi Our version of the Inverse Function Theorem is explicitly stated and proven only for maps $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n.$ We cannot apply the theorem in the book to function into the complex numbers. The example doesn't work in this context. Also, with how many mistakes have been made in the book, I really wouldn't be surprised if the author was wrong.

Comment: The inversion function theorem only gives you information about local inverses, the passage from local to global using that theorem requires often a lot of work and various consideration (as my example shows). Also, it is not very interesting for function defined over $\mathbb{R}$. (And $\mathbb{C} \sim \mathbb{R}^2$, so it is not very hard do modify my example to suit your needs.)

Comment: @nicomezi I understand that. The book tells us we are to use the theorem in this exercise to show a function has local derivatives. Not using the theorem show it has no global derivatives. This doesn't work with the domain the author gives us.

Comment: It works, but the range cannot be $\mathbb{R}$ in order to satisfy the condition, as you have proven it. Consider $x \mapsto (\cos x, \sin x)$. The inequality $f'(x) \ne 0$ being here understood as an inequality between linear maps.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ whose
derivative never vanishes must be injective. In fact, [Darboux's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)) guarantees that $f'(x)$ cannot change sign, so it is either positive everywhere or negative everywhere, which implies that $f$ is a strictly monotone function, either strictly decreasing or strictly increasing, so it is injective indeed.

So either the author of your book means that the range of the function is not $\mathbb{R}$, or, if she/he does, it is a mistake.